# WPF User Control Binding get data

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls

I'm new to WPF and binding stuff. I was trying to find a solution to my problem, but still missing something ;/
I would like to get data from TextBox which is in UserControl and put it to a property in which is in a main window, on way it work, but other not ;/

I have a simple class

```
public class User
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Age {get; set;}
}
```

and a simple user control called UserDetails with a two TextBoxs

```
<TextBox Text="{Bind Name}" />
<TextBox Text="{Bind Age}" />
```

UserDetails UC is placed on main window like this:

```
<uc:UserDetails DataContext="{Binding User, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

and in MainWindow ViewModel I have a property

```
public User User { get; set;}
```

on MainWindow there is also a button that on click should fill up User property with data from UserDetials UC.
It's quite late now and I need to have it done by morning, so any straight solution would be appreciated.

Any ideas how to do it ? The example above is very simple, but If you could show me the way how to do it, I could handle rest of my problem.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot? If you are binding like this you don't need to click a button to fill the 'User' with the details from the UserControl. You should bind User directly to the usercontrol, when you change the text in the textbox, the property on User will change immediately

Comment: The button is needed to get the data from User property and save them in DB. But always when I fill both TextBoxes and click the button the User property is Null. It's hard to post any screenshots because my application is much more complicated the the example above, but the problem is the same.

Comment: @suleks This isn't a free code factory where you can state a problem and expect the good users of SO to respond with the full code solution because you need to complete an assignment and need it by the morn. We'll offer help, often with code examples or helpful links, but that kind of request rubs SO users the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some things to try:

- Make sure you're setting your view model to the MainWindow's DataContext. Even if you're not using a separate class for your view model and are just using code-behind, you need to assign the DataContext.
- It might just be a typo, but in your text boxes, you've written `{Bind Name}` when it should be `{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}` and the same for the Age. You need to set the binding mode to two way on the property, not on the class as you have in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and fire the PropertyChanged event in the property setter. You'll need to do it for your `MainViewModel` and `User` classes. Here's an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) of how it is done.